# How can I precisely detect all OnePlus devices?

Tags: android, react-native, fonts, expo

The text of my mobile application was cut off on OnePlus devices, and my app does use custom font until now.
I searched for some [information](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15114) and learned that change the font of my app might be helpful.

Thanks to Expo they have some [methods](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/device/) that could get the exact devices information, I want to use the default font only for OnePlus devices.

But I don't how can I precisely detect OnePlus devices.
Or should I say if I use the detect [methods](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/device/) of Expo on OnePlus devices, I don't know what will be returned.

And also, purchasing OnePlus mobile phones is too expensive for me...

Comment: What information, exactly, are you looking for?

Comment: What I think you want is just Build.MANUFACTURER, and then do a string contains on that. I don't know what oneplus devices use as that though,

Comment: Right. I guess it will be string, too. But what exactly it is...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting device info you can just make allowFontScaling as false in Text tag.

```
<Text allowFontScaling={false}>Your text goes here</Text>
```

This will avoid text cut.

Comment: Turning off an accessibility setting is never a solution for a problem, it just creates another one.